# how to get Json from a Json Url in Android Studio?

Tags: android, json

I have the following code to retrieve Json from raw file:

```
@Override
protected RecyclerView.Adapter getAdapter() {
    if (adapter == null) {
        String jsonStr = readRawFile();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        VideoPage videoPage = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, VideoPage.class);
        adapter = new VideoAdapter(videoPage);
    }
    return adapter;
}

String readRawFile() {
    String content = "";
    Resources resources = getContext().getResources();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.video_list);
        byte buffer[] = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(buffer);
        content = new String(buffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

File video_list.json : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnIxw.jpg)

```
"data": [
{
  "title": "Video 1",
  "imgUrl": "http://example.com/",
  "videoUrl": "http://example.com/",
  "docUrl": "http://example.com/"
},
{
  "title": "Video 2",
  "imgUrl": "http://example.com//",
  "videoUrl": "http://example.com/",
  "docUrl": "http://example.com/"
},
```

Now I do not want to get Json from this video_list file, I want to get the Json file from an url containing Json. Can someone help me code again?

Comment: Use AsyncTask/volley/retrofit

Comment: You can copy this json ,paste it in http://myjson.com/  then get you url.....then try it by using asynctask/volley/retrofit

Comment: Can you help me write code it? Thanks!